# How to hide/not-support Outlook add-in for Mac?

Tags: office-js

We have developed an add-in that does not work with Outlook 2015 for Mac due to the `saveAsync()` method not being supported.

Until this is supported we don’t want our add-in to appear for Outlook 2016 for Mac. The only settings that I could find to control add-in availability is through requirement sets but I can't find one that would hide this on the Mac.

Is it possible to specify in the manifest that this Add-in doesn't support Outlook 2016 for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to flag a specific version or platform as supported or not supported from within the manifest.  You could however check to see if the current client is Outlook 2016 for Mac and display an different page in the taskpane that informs the user that this add-in doesn't support Outlook 2016 for Mac.

If you're planning to publish to the Office Store, they **can** flag that the add-in doesn't support Mac. You would need to explain this in your Testing Notes during publishing. If they have questions they will reach out to clarify.

A more interesting question is why you're dependent on `saveAsync()` when creating a calendar item. Could you explain your scenario that required saving a draft copy? It may be possible to find an alternative solution for Mac users (or at least provide valuable feedback for the Outlook team).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am already displaying a message on MAC which says clearly that the add-in is not supported on MAC. we got a rejection from office team during add-in testing, I will update the notes for testing and try again.

Comment: We need to find the event Id, and event unique Id(iCalUid). With the current Office-js api the only way I am aware is that we need to do saveAsync to get the Id, there are lot for feature request regarding the same on office user voice forum

Answer (score -2):

I'm having a similar problem with `saveAsync()` not being supported by the Mac client.

My scenario is that I'm dependent of having an `itemId` which my application use to link the event to a specific instance in said application.

A user should be able to bring up the event with the add-in in the client and already have it synced to my application, or navigate to our application and have it synced the other way around.

Since the custom properties are not shared between users this can become quite problematic.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer